# Как избежать ошибок TypeScript при импорте сторонних Vue-компонентов, написанных на TypeScript?

Tags: vue.js, typescript

У меня возникла следующая ошибка при попытке импорта Vue-компонента извне директории проекта:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '{ template: string; components: { SimpleCheckbox: typeof SimpleCheckbox; }; }' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 'VueClass<Vue>'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'template' does not exist in type 
'VueClass<Vue>'.
```

Это ошибка произошла в следующем файле:

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import template from './SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.pug';
import SimpleCheckbox from './../../../../ui-kit-libary-in-development/UiComponents/Checkboxes/MaterialDesign/SimpleCheckbox.vue';

// здесь!
@Component({ template, components: { SimpleCheckbox } }) 
export default class SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel extends Vue {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly text!: string;
}
```

Как это следует из имени `ui-kit-libary-in-development`, это (пока что) не npm-зависимость, а потому она и не находится в `node_modules`.

Возникшая ошибка является исключительно ошибкой TypeScript-а, потому что хотя её
`typescript-loader` и бросает, в собранном Webpack-ом JavaScript-е никаких ошибок нет; все компоненты отображаются и реагируют на действия пользователя согласно задумке.

Ошибка TypeScript-а исчезнет, если выполнить одно из следующих действий:

- Временно переместить `SimpleCheckbox.vue` в ту же директорию, что и `SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel.ts` и импортировать его как `import SimpleCheckbox from './SimpleCheckbox.vue';`
- Убрать `SimpleCheckbox` из `@Component({ template, components: { SimpleCheckbox } })` и оставить только `@Component({ template, components: {} })` (естественно, что `SimpleCheckbox` в этом случае отрендерен не будет, но результат этого эксперимента показывает, что в самих компонентах ошибок TypeScript нет).
- Переместить `ui-kit-libary-in-development` в `node_modules` основного проекта, при этом удалить `node_modules` из `ui-kit-libary-in-development` (если не удалять - будет та же ошибка).

К сожалению, я не смог воспроизвести эту проблему. В приведённой ниже попытке воспроизведения схема импорта `Button.vue` та же самая, что и SimpleCheckbox, но почему-то в `@Component({ template, components: { Button } })` аналогичной ошибки не возникает.

**MainProject/src/Application.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
  PageOne
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import PageOne from './PageComponents/PageOne'

  @Component({ components: { PageOne }})
  export default class Application extends Vue {
    private created(): void {
      console.log('Done.');
    }
  }
</script>
```

**MainProject/src/PageComponents/PageOne.ts**

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import template from './PageOne.pug';
import Button from './../../../UiKitLibraryStillInDevelopment/UiComponents/Buttons/Button.vue';


// Почему-то всё нормально!
@Component({ template, components: { Button } })
export default class SkipProjectInitializationStepPanel extends Vue {}
```

**MainProject/src/PageComponents/PageOne.pug**

```
.RootElement
  Button(:text="'Click me'")
```

**ui-kit-libary-in-development/UiComponents/Buttons/Button.vue**

```
<template lang="pug">
  button {{ text }}
</template>


<script lang="ts">
  import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class SimpleCheckbox extends Vue {
    @Prop({ type: String, required: true }) private readonly text!: string;

    private created(): void {
      console.log('OK!');
      console.log(this.$props);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Видимо, я не учёл что-то ещё. Естественно, что при попытке нагуглить информацию по данной ошибке во Vue-проектах дала весьма скудную информацию, и пожалуй единственная ценная подсказка была найдена на странице Git-hub-билета [Setting components in Component decorator causes Typescript 2.4 error](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component/issues/123):

> Side components should add .d.ts for it to work AFAIK.
>
> Насколько мне известно, для сторонних компонентов должны быть определения типов `.d.ts`.
>
> [Nick Messing](https://github.com/nickmessing)

Ну, или если переводить совсем дословно, то эти компоненты должны добавлять `.d.ts`, но понятно, что это может сделать только либо TypeScript-компилятор, либо человек.

Эта подсказка порождает новые вопросы:

- Куда добавлять новый `.d.ts` - в свой проект или в зависимость? Скорее всего в свой, но если так, то за счёт чего же мы можем импортировать компоненты из таких библиотек из `vuetify`? Потому что там есть `.d.ts`!
- Как вообще правильно объявлять новые Vue-компоненты в `.d.ts`? Есть ли какие-нибудь уроки или примеры, понятные для тех, кто впервые объявляет типы для Vue-компонентов?

---

### Исходные файлы для конкурса

Поскольку моя библиотека ещё сырая и не имеет особой ценности, я её выложу по крайней мере на время конкурса. [Этот архив на Яндекс-диске](https://yadi.sk/d/zeH2bWMtoSWMWw) включает в себя основной проект и зависимость; все node_modules в комплекте. Всё, что нужно для воспроизведения проблемы - это в директории `main-project` запустить команду `npm run developmentBuild`.

Comment: Тут в интернетах пишут про параметр "strictFunctionTypes":false  в "compilerOptions" в настройках ts . Так себе решение, как по мне.

Comment: @zalex, а Вы бы не могли сказать причину, по которой эта ошибка произошла и почему предложенное Вами решение хоть и не очень, но работает?

Comment: Боюсь я сварщик в ts не настоящий, однако вывод про "так себе решение"  я сделал исходя лишь из того что данная опция отключает включенную по умолчанию проверку функций, описанную тут https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html  , предполагаю так же что по-хорошему нужно покопать и все таки найти причину, но повторю,  я в ts не настоящий сварщик :)

Comment: @zalex, ничего страшного, я благодарен Вам уже только за то, что Вы прочли мой вопрос и попытались ответить на него, как смогли!